# Bootstrap-sass supports colored table row markup from Bootstrap 2.1.0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a new site and using it as an excuse to play with sass-bootstrap. During the course of creating the main layout of the site, I found that I cannot do any table markup with regards to coloring the rows using [the examples](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#tables) listed under "Optional Row Classes" on. Specifically `<tr class="success">` or `="error"`.

This is the view code for a raid controller monitor:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="span12 row">&nbsp;</div>

<div class="span12 row">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr><th>Server</th><th>Status</th><th>Spare</th><th>Last Update</th></tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <% @raids.each do |raid| %>
                <% if raid.status == "OK" && raid.spare == "OK" %>
                    <tr class="success">                    
                <% else %>
                    <tr class="error">
                <% end %>
                    <td><%= raid.hostname %></td>
                    <td><%= raid.status %></td>
                    <td><%= raid.spare %></td>
                    <td><%= time_ago_in_words(raid.update_time) %> ago</td>
                </tr>
            <% end %>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</div>
```

My gems:

```
    Using rake (0.9.2.2) 
    Using i18n (0.6.0) 
    Using multi_json (1.3.5) 
    Using activesupport (3.2.3) 
    Using builder (3.0.0) 
    Using activemodel (3.2.3) 
    Using erubis (2.7.0) 
    Using journey (1.0.3) 
    Using rack (1.4.1) 
    Using rack-cache (1.2) 
    Using rack-test (0.6.1) 
    Using hike (1.2.1) 
    Using tilt (1.3.3) 
    Using sprockets (2.1.3) 
    Using actionpack (3.2.3) 
    Using mime-types (1.18) 
    Using polyglot (0.3.3) 
    Using treetop (1.4.10) 
    Using mail (2.4.4) 
    Using actionmailer (3.2.3) 
    Using arel (3.0.2) 
    Using tzinfo (0.3.33) 
    Using activerecord (3.2.3) 
    Using activeresource (3.2.3) 
    Using addressable (2.2.8) 
    Using annotate (2.4.1.beta1) 
    Using bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1) 
    **Using bootstrap-sass (2.1.0.0)**
    Using nokogiri (1.5.2) 
    Using ffi (1.0.11) 
    Using childprocess (0.3.2) 
    Using libwebsocket (0.1.3) 
    Using rubyzip (0.9.8) 
    Using selenium-webdriver (2.21.2) 
    Using xpath (0.1.4) 
    Using capybara (1.1.2) 
    Using coffee-script-source (1.3.1) 
    Using execjs (1.3.2) 
    Using coffee-script (2.2.0) 
    Using rack-ssl (1.3.2) 
    Using json (1.7.3) 
    Using rdoc (3.12) 
    Using thor (0.14.6) 
    Using railties (3.2.3) 
    Using coffee-rails (3.2.2) 
    Using diff-lcs (1.1.3) 
    Using factory_girl (3.2.0) 
    Using factory_girl_rails (3.2.0) 
    Using faker (1.0.1) 
    Using guard (1.0.3) 
    Using guard-rspec (0.5.5) 
    Using jquery-rails (2.0.2) 
    Using libnotify (0.5.9) 
    Using libv8 (3.3.10.4) 
    Using mysql (2.8.1) 
    Using bundler (1.1.4) 
    Using rails (3.2.3) 
    Using rb-readline (0.4.2) 
    Using rspec-core (2.9.0) 
    Using rspec-expectations (2.9.1) 
    Using rspec-mocks (2.9.0) 
    Using rspec (2.9.0) 
    Using rspec-rails (2.9.0)  
    Using sass (3.1.18) 
    Using sass-rails (3.2.5) 
    Using sqlite3 (1.3.6) 
    Using therubyracer (0.10.1) 
    Using uglifier (1.2.4)
```

Comment: I've tried (copy & paste) your code and it works as expected - so the problem is probably somewhere else. 

Are you sure that you have `@import "bootstrap"` in your manifest file (typically `application.css.sass`)?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, Radek. I have '@import "bootstrap";' at the top of my custom.css.scss file and other bootstrap-y things seem to work (like <table class="table"> formats the table correctly). I thought this might be an issue with versions of bootstrap, but I appear to have the latest one.

Comment: Interestingly enough, this seems restricted to my development environment (using "rails server"), when I push to my production environment (nginx/passenger) it runs perfectly with colorized tables.

Comment: maybe it's a problem with SASS caches - sometimes changing timestamp of the asset scss file helps (adding empty line there and save is enough) or you can try `rake assets:clean`.